# in mongodb, how to design a bus station schema in this situation

Tags: mongodb

I have a schema to build, it is a bus station application, which stores the distance or other info between two nearby bus stations, it is unlikely to store one station id for the index or unique key, I think a better to do it is to group station 1 and station 2 as unique and index key, but I am a bit not confident whether it is the right way to do it, put 2 bus stations id into a array, make this array as index and unique key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds very reasonable... It's a "relationship table" or a many-to-many join table with additional attributes. You would store the distance as an attribute of the M:N relationship./ the two bus station ids would form the composite primary key.

Look at the image in section 2.1.5 of [this modeling guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15276_01/doc.20/e13677/tut_data_modeling.htm)

You may want to learn a little bit about database design techniques. If so, some useful sources on databases and modeling are:

- [Fundamentals of Database Systems by Elmasri and Nevathi](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fundamentals-Database-Systems-International-Version/dp/032141506X/ref=pd_sim_sbs_b_1) - Very technical about all aspects of database and covers modeling in depth
- [An Introduction to Database Systems by CJ Date](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Database-Systems-C-J-Date/dp/0321189566/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1362674725&sr=1-1) - similar to above
- [A Tutorial on Normal Form (BCNF)](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27785&seqNum=3) - BCNF prescribes a means of bringing out your data model by iteratively applying a rule to your model till it meets normal form (is efficient - barring intended redundancy).
- [Wikipedia entry looks pretty concise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) - as above re BCNF but looks nice and concise (perhaps focus on sections 3 and 4)

**EDIT: Update relevant to Mongo DB**

Actually, the above is all pretty general for database modeling. Having a read of some of the excellent resources on [Data Modeling Considerations for MongoDB Applications](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) I think you need more specific guidance.

As such, I refer you to this informative SO post: [how-to-organise-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839881/how-to-organise-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-mongodb). The author gives a good explanation that sounds like what you're after. There's even references to docs and a video.