# How can I create unique IDs for embedded documents in MongoDB using PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection of `posts`

```
{
  "uid": ObjectId("57e58f6a1ccbdd1407000029"),
  "text": "Post content goes here!",
  "comments": [
    {
      "_id": // unique ID
      "comment": "Comment 1",
    },
    {
      "_id": // unique ID
      "comment": "Comment 2",
    }
  ]
}
```

The above is a simple example of the post collection's document structure.

I was thinking that, what would be the best way to generate and store a unique id (using PHP) for each comment so that it could be selected specifically to edit or delete.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: If you need a unique ID, a subdue is probably a bad Idea and you should use a dedicated collection. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409635/mongodb-query-comments-along-with-user-information/32411030#32411030 for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Markus' comment, but to answer the question you should consider

1. generating BSON ObjectId which is [pretty much unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694803/5982920) and doesn't require anything additional
2. generating UUID using for instance [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid)