# MongoDB Many To One Relation

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb,Lets say `User` can create many `Events`,where Each Event Belongs to  only one `User`.So in Relational Database I created `Events` Table Where I store `UserId`  who created the Event, with details about event , what's the best way to handle this relation in monogdb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to organise a many to many relationship in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839881/how-to-organise-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-mongodb)

Comment: @HarshaW sorry for mistake i made in question, in events table where each row contain details about event and user who created the event,i didn't create any new table to store event and user id .whether the link which u have given me now is fine for this case??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, use embedded data models when: you have `one-to-one` or `one-to-many` model, more information you can find [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design).