# How to structure many-to-many relationships in mongoose nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The scenario is as follows:

One `product` can be in **Many** `orders`, and one `order` can have many `products`. How to structure **many-to-many** relationships using `mongoose` and `node.js` ?

I have given the product model below. However, I am not sure how the order model should be. Can someone please help me figure this out. I am new to Node/ Mongoose and hope someone will help me out with this.

CODE

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    product:{
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    price:{
        type: String,

        required: true

    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        deault: Date.now
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Many-to-Many Association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336700/mongodb-many-to-many-association)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my product model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    product:{
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    price:{
        type: String,

        required: true

    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        deault: Date.now
    }
});
var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports = product;
```

this order model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        orderNumber:{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        products:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Product'}]
        create_date:{
            type: Date,
            deault: Date.now
        }
    });

    var Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
module.exports = Order;
```

my result of json like this

product :

```
{
    _id:1
    product:"test",
    price:100,
    create_date:"20/11/91"

}
```

order :

```
{
    orderNumber:123
    product: [1] (ref of product id)
    create_date:"20/11/91"
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how the `product`s model looks like. And also how to create the `order` (by showing me the JSON)

Comment: I am getting this error `"Cast to Array failed for value \"1\" at path \"product\""`