# Correct MongoDB hierarchy to use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building an app for sharing summaries between students that behaves like a social network.

A signed user will be able to upload summaries and access a feed of uploaded summaries.

The way I have it right now:

**user schema:**

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username : String,
    password : String,
    summeries: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
  });
```

**summaries schema:**

```
var summerySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    username : String,
    date: Date
});
```

I want to change it so that summerySchema is embedded to userSchema like this:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username : String,
    password : String,
    summeries: [summerySchema]
  });
```

but if do so, how do I query the (let's say) 10 newest summaries from all users? (without going through the entire database? in fear of very long wait time and server overload).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB relationships: embed or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Many-to-Many Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336700/mongodb-many-to-many-association)

Comment: thank you for your comments. I edited the post according to these posts with an updated question.