# MongoDB - Retrieve data with many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, mongodb, many-to-many

Suppose I have to simple objects stored in mongoDB with many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Person {
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public List<Guid> Groups {get; set;}
}
public class Group {
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public List<Guid> Persons {get; set;}
}
```

So, any person might belong to a number of groups while any group consists of number of persons. I'm trying to find the **most efficient way to retrieve persons (or groups) data using .NET driver and, if possible, avoid to run multiple queries** for this purpose:

Processing "get person by Id" request I expect to have a data described as following:

```
PersonModel: {
   Id: <Guid>,
   Name: <string>,
   Groups: [
     { Id: <Guid>, Title: <string> },
     { Id: <Guid>, Title: <string> },
     ...
   ]
}
```

and the result of "get group by Id" request is expected to be as following:

```
GroupModel: {
   Id: <Guid>,
   Title: <string>,
   Persons: [
     { Id: <Guid>, Name: <string> },
     { Id: <Guid>, Name: <string> },
     ...
   ]
}
```

Any suggestions will be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is there any restriction on "max no. of the person" in a group or "max. no. of the group" a person can join?

Comment: Is this help you a bit? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336700/mongodb-many-to-many-association. As far as I know using Spring with this @DBRef annotation to declare object for role like this private Set<Role> roles;

Comment: It can be modeled with persons embedded in group _or_ groups embedded in person (not both, I think). An important question is: which is the most queried (the person with groups _or_ the group with persons). For other queries you have to do with referencing, like using the aggregation's `$lookup`.  Modeling N:N relationship is complex, and you have to analyze well ahead what kind of queries and updates are important and then build your data design.

Comment: In the worse case there is no restrictions on "max no. of the person" in a group or "max. no. of the group"