# How do I use many-to-many in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Using articles and tags as an example,

please describe the table design to me, preferably involving the actions that need to be taken care of during CRUD

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336700/mongodb-many-to-many-association

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB Many-to-Many Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336700/mongodb-many-to-many-association)